# VM Capabilities, what kind of VM can support these two kind of hot code replace: "Method addition" and "Arbitrary class redefinition"?

Tags: eclipse, virtual-machine, hotdeploy

In Eclipse debug view, right click to show the context menu, open the properties dialog, click the second tab "VM Capabilities", which says "this page displays optional debug capabilities that may be supported by the selected VM". In "Hot Code Replace" area, the "Method addition" and "Arbitrary class redefinition" is not checked, my question is what kind of VM can support these two kind of hot code replace?[image: eclipse debug properties-Hot Code Replace]